# Opentok Network Test gives OT_STREAM_DESTROYED error

Tags: javascript, vonage

I've implemented Opentok Network Test on an videocall application, one year ago, and it worked fine till 3-4 days ago. Now it works for a test or two, but it fails on the next many tries:

opentok.min.js:26 OpenTok:Session:error OT_STREAM_DESTROYED: Stream was destroyed before it could be subscribed to +0ms

opentok.min.js:26 OpenTok:GlobalExceptionHandler:error OT.exception :: title: undefined (undefined) msg: Stream was destroyed before it could be subscribed to +0ms

I'm running opentok version 2.26.4 and opentok-network-test-js version 3.1.1
Implementation code is right from the network test github page documentation.

Any one using this feature had any issues lately? Thanks

Tried to make multiple network tests

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.